# jquery textarea resize both width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create jQuery plugin for both Firefox and Chrome that will make `textarea` to auto grow for both height and width.
[This is what I have done](http://jsfiddle.net/8SMMn/).

HTML:

```
<div class="textbox">
    <textarea>Some Text</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.textbox {
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px dashed #CCCCCC;
    min-width: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
}


.textbox textarea {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    resize: none;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.hiddendiv {
    display: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.textbox = function(options) {
        options = options || {};

        var maxWidth = options.maxWidth || $(window).width(),
            maxHeight = options.maxHeight || $(window).height();

        this.each(function() {
            var elem = $(this),
                clone = $("<div class='hiddendiv'></div>").appendTo("body"),
                textarea = elem.find("textarea"),
                content = "";

            function setMaxSize() {
                var widthSpace = elem.outerWidth(true) - elem.width();
                var heightSpace = elem.outerHeight(true) - elem.height();
                var newMax = {
                    "max-width": maxWidth - widthSpace,
                    "max-height": maxHeight - heightSpace
                };

                elem.css(newMax);
                clone.css(newMax);
            }

            function adjust() {
                clone.css({
                    "font-family": textarea.css("font-family"),
                    "font-size": textarea.css("font-size")
                });

                content = textarea.val().replace(/\n/g, '<br>&nbsp;');
                if (content === "") {
                    content = "&nbsp;";
                }

                clone.html(content);

                elem.css({
                    height: clone.height(),
                    width: clone.width() + 5
                });
            }
            textarea.on("keyup", adjust);

            setMaxSize();
            adjust();

        });
    };

    $(".textbox").textbox();
});
```

I have a few problems:

1. Whenever I type a letter and expand the box, only in Firefox I get weird blinking. How can I get rid of that blinking?
2. In Chrome, when I type a letter, the first letter is moving backward and then return to its position. How can I prevent this?
3. In Chrome, whenever I type a long word, "Sdfsdfsdfwejhrkjsdhfsdf" for example, the text doesn't break a new line when reach to max-width, but a new line appears. How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css transition on `.textbox` element, i.e.: `transition: all 0.5s;`

Comment: I don't think this would solve the problem, can you use my jsfiddle and show me how?

Comment: the problem with the blinking in FF is caused by jumping some part of the text into another line and going back after resize. I would recommend you to resize the box first.